# Kodi JSON-RPC over TCP invalid message

Tags: java, json, kodi

I'm sending this json over a tcp-socket to my raspi-kodi-client.

```
{"method":"Playlist.Clear","id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":[{"playlistid":1}]}
```

But he returns me:

```
{"error":{"code":-32602,"data":{"method":"Playlist.Clear","stack":{"message":"Invalid type object received","name":"playlistid","type":"integer"}},"message":"Invalid params."},"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Why??? It's look like I'm too stupidooo because diffrent examples looks same

[First Example - ok its http not tcp but I dont think thats the point - but maybe it is :O](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=157996)

I'm using kodi 1.7 and openjdk 11.

Comment: In all the examples in that link, "params" is an _object_, not an _array_. And that fact is exactly what the error message is telling you (although I admit, it's not saying it very clearly).

Comment: @Adyon I just said: I'm too stupidoo. Thx. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the examples in that link, "params" is an *object*, not an *array*. And that fact is exactly what the error message is telling you (although I admit, it's not saying it very clearly).

Simply change

```
{"method":"Playlist.Clear","id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":[{"playlistid":1}]}
```

to

```
{"method":"Playlist.Clear","id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":{"playlistid":1}}
```

Comment: But why the doc's saying params is an array? 
https://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API/v8#Playlist.Clear
Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: I'm not very familar with JSON schemas but I think the reason "params" in that schema is an array is because it's making a list of all the possible parameter values you can supply - these would all be properties of the "params" object in your submitted data. I don't think it's actually saying that the thing you submit must be an array. Apologies if I'm wrong but that's my reading of it (without having studied the topic at all).